# Joining 2 tables and echoing the values via JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, inner-join, encode

I have a problem with `JSON` codes. I want to echo this:

```
[{"post_title":"hospital-name","term_taxonomy_id":"15,16,20"}, 
{"post_title":"hospital-name","term_taxonomy_id":"15,16,20"} ]
```

**and I am using this code:**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT fd_posts.post_content , fd_posts.post_title , fd_posts.id, fd_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id  FROM fd_posts INNER JOIN fd_term_relationships 
ON fd_posts.id=fd_term_relationships.object_id WHERE fd_posts.post_type='hospitals'");

    $stmt->execute();
    $myarr = array();
    while ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $myarr[] = array('id' => $data['id'], 'post_title' => $data['post_title']);

    }
    echo json_encode($myarr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

**but it outputs this:**

```
[
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"120","post_title":"hospital-name"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"},
    {"id":"125","post_title":"hospital-name-2"}
]
```

How can I change my `PHP` code to echo the desired `JSON`?

Comment: can you tell what is the exact issue and what is the result you want ?

Comment: The JSON you want it to output is invalid. Just paste it into http://json.parser.online.fr. The code `{post_id:5:{post-title:"hospital-name"}}` is invalid for a number of reasons. 1) There's no such thing as a key-value-value pair (tuple?); 2) `post-title` needs to be in quotes. `{"post_id":5,"post-title:"hostpital-name}` is valid, and is already being output.

Comment: Where is the error? You have to create a multiarray

Comment: in fact i want to show : [post_id:5:{"post_title":"hospital-name","post-content:"my-content-2","term_taxonomy_id":[15,13,14]} post_id:6:{"post_title":"hospital-name-2","term_taxonomy_id":[20,13,21]} ]

Comment: Just as @Plato says, that's not valid Json so if you want that format, you would need to write your own encoder and decoder.

Comment: I do not want to repeat this sort of Jason for every taxonomy

Comment: i have a problem with my loop (while)

Comment: Are you actually reading our comments?

Comment: @magnus Eriksson yes! ok. can you tell me how make a correct loop to don't repeat.

Comment: Is it true?
 [{"post_title":"hospital-name","term_taxonomy_id":"15,16,20"},
{"post_title":"hospital-name","term_taxonomy_id":"15,16,20"} ]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT fd_posts.post_content, fd_posts.post_title , fd_posts.id, fd_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
                    FROM fd_posts 
                    INNER JOIN fd_term_relationships ON fd_posts.id = fd_term_relationships.object_id 
                    WHERE fd_posts.post_type='hospitals'");

$stmt->execute();
$myarr = array();
while ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $myarr[] = array(
        'post_title' => $data['post_title'],
        'term_taxonomy_id' => $data['term_taxonomy_id'], 
    );
}
echo json_encode($myarr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: it show that

[{"post_title":"hospital-name","term_taxonomy_id":"2"},
{"post_title":"hospital-name","term_taxonomy_id":"7"},
{"post_title":"hospital-name-2","term_taxonomy_id":"2"},
{"post_title":"hospital-name-2","term_taxonomy_id":"7"}]

Comment: You need to correct `$myarr` based on data coming from sql and it will be fixed

Comment: can you explain more ? I really don't have any idea

Comment: @Amin.A show me the screenshot of phpmyadmin running the above query in code

Comment: I sent it for you.